# Kohana DB expression not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

Can someone please explain how to get the first query to return the same results as the 2nd query? The first query returns 1 instead of 0 for any column with a count of 0. The 2nd query works fine. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the COUNT() statement.

```
$lists = DB::select('favorites_lists.*', array(DB::expr('COUNT("favorites.list_id")'), 'total_favs'))
    ->from('favorites_lists')
    ->join('favorites', 'LEFT')
    ->on('favorites_lists.id', '=', 'favorites.list_id')
    ->where('favorites_lists.uid', '=', $user->id)
    ->group_by('favorites_lists.id')
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();

$lists = DB::query(
    Database::SELECT,
    'SELECT favorites_lists.*, COUNT(favorites.list_id) as total_favs
    FROM favorites_lists
    LEFT JOIN favorites
    ON favorites_lists.id = favorites.list_id
    WHERE favorites_lists.uid = ' . $user->id . '
    GROUP BY favorites_lists.id'
)
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::select('favorites_lists.*', array(DB::expr('COUNT("favorites.list_id")'), 'total_favs'))
```

what's the use of this array ? I usually write the query like this .

```
DB::select('favorites_lists.*',DB::expr('COUNT("favorites.list_id") AS total_favs'))
```

Comment: That's just what the Kohana docs showed in their example. I uncommented my original code and it's working now. I have no idea what changed, but before all my debugging showed the incorrect result was coming from the database, so I have no idea. Your expression works just fine too, so I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted. If anything this post will help people trying to wade through Kohana's incomplete and confusing documentation :) One thing though, you need an extra parentheses at the end.